# Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Sprite' before initialization

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I'm currently programming a web game and I'm stuck here, could someone help me?
I've tried different ways but I've been stuck here for a few hours so I thought I'd write here, I'm a junior programmer and I'm using this page for the first time, if I've described something wrong I apologize.

Uncaught ReferenceError: Cannot access 'Sprite' before initialization

```
const backgorund = new Sprite({
  position: {
    x: 0,
    y: 0
  },
  imageSrc: './img/background.png'
})

class Sprite {
    constructor({position, velocity, imageSrc}) {
        this.position = position
        this.velocity = velocity
        this.width = 50
        this.height = 150
        this.image = new Image()
        this.image.src = imageSrc
    }
    draw() {
      c.drawImage(this.image, this.position.x, this.position.y)

    }
    update() {
        this.draw()
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to initialize a class before use.  Move your class declaration on top:

```js
class Sprite {
  // ...
}

const backgorund = new Sprite({
   // ...
})
```

Comment: You may want to mark the answer as accepted then.

Comment: This is really annoying for some people. Great answer. vote up+